# Display Attachment URL in single.php in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

i've been trying to get the attachment URL, so far this code gets the DIRECT LINK to the image ;

```
<?php if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type'=>'image',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
     )));
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID )  . '">Download Full Size</a>';
 }

 ?>
```

but instead i want the attachment URL, please help...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong way, Have you stored URL of upload file in DB ?
If no then you can't.

Use custom fields to store and use them.

If you want to it without coding use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use [get_attachment_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link) instead of wp_get_attachement_url